# Possible to get R5RS code to work with SchemeUnit?

Tags: list, scheme, racket, r5rs

In a class I am taking we are using the old R5RS standard of Scheme to solve SICP assignments. I like to do test first development, so I figured a unit testing framework would be nice, and I chose SchemeUnit for writing the small tests.

This has worked fine so far, just testing primitives in the output (strings, numbers, ...), but I hit a road block when trying to test lists. It  has probably something to do with differences in the Scheme dialect used to run the tests:

**foo.scm:** `(define a-list (list 2))`

**foo-tests.scm:**  `(check-equal? a-list (list 2))`

Result when running the tests:

```
Unnamed test 
FAILURE
name:       check-equal?
location:   tester.scm:22:3
actual:     {2}

expected:   (2)
```

To make the test suite run, I have to add `"#lang scheme/base`  to the top of foo-tests.scm and `require` the schemeunit package. In foo.scm I need to have `#lang r5rs` and `(#%provide (all-defined))` at the top.

I guess lists are somehow differently implemented in R5RS and "scheme/base". Any way to get them to work together? And why does it fail ({} vs ())?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as you've noticed, lists are implemented differently in `#lang r5rs` vs `#lang scheme/base`.  If it's possible to write the tests in your `foo-tests.scm` in r5rs, that would  help to eliminate the possible confusion.

You should be able to do this by having this at the top of your `foo-tests.scm` file.

```
#lang r5rs

(#%require schemeunit)
(#%require "foo.scm")

;; Now you can add your tests here:
(check-equal? a-list (list 1 2 3))
```

If the test suite is written in the same language, then the constructs --- and in particular, the representation for lists --- should match up.  The test above should hopefully pass.

To elaborate on the difference between the `r5rs` lists and the one in `#lang scheme` (and `#lang racket`): Racket uses immutable cons pairs to represent lists.  Immutable cons pairs do not support the `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` functions of r5rs, so it wouldn't be faithful to the standard for the `#lang r5rs` language to use the built-in immutable pairs.  To support the r5rs standard, Racket includes a separate [mutable pairs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html) data type, and uses it consistently within r5rs.  But it means that the standard pairs in Racket and the mutable pairs do not compare equally.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer. I understand "Planet" to be some kind of dependency management app (like Maven in the Java world). In addition to just scheme unit, I also need a text runner to actually run the tests and display the result. What would I add to the (#require) part that would be the equivalent of
(require (planet schematics/schemeunit:3/text-ui))?

Comment: In modern Racket, know that the unit testing framework comes with Racket's standard library now.  See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/index.html.  Don't use the one in PLaneT, as it's actually the ancestor of `rackunit`.  You don't need an explicit test runner if you're using the `check-equal?` thing: just running the test module should be enough to drive the tests.  If you do need a explicit test runner (for more sophisticated testing), see the rest of http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/quick-start.html.  But for what you're doing in r5rs, I don't see the complexity to be worth it.

Comment: Thanks. Found out that the required syntax was (#%require schemeunit/text-ui). Then I "upgraded" to racket's built-in by changing to 
#lang r5rs
(#%require rackunit)
(#%require rackunit/text-ui)
(#%require "foo.scm") and defining a minimal test. Seems to work like I want to. Thanks a lot. Mind if I add this info to your answer?